# CSS Selector for first-child after a page break

Tags: css

How can I style the first-child *AFTER* a page break has occurred?

The ultimate situation I'm facing is that I would like to style the first row of a table differently, and when printing the table spans multiple pages. I successfully used :first-child to style the first row. I also successfully avoided page breaks inside rows. I can not figure out how to style the first row on the second page of the table, though.

I'm familiar with the css pseudo class first-child (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp), and I'm also familiar with the css print property page-break-inside (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp). I'm unable to get them to play nicely together?

EDIT:
Adding code sample

```
HTML:
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

CSS:
table tr:first-child td { border-top: solid red 2px; }
table tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: A page break is not an element, so I don't think a CSS selector could work in this scenario.

Comment: We would need to see your HTML/CSS structure

Comment: There is no needs to html/css, question is clear enough.

Comment: Do you know how many rows there are per printed page and will that number be consistent? You could target them using `nth-child`. For instance, 10 rows per page would be: `table tr:nth-child(11n)` which means "Select every 11th row". [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/navaxi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam it can work wrong. Someone have a few different page margin, and you will get different result (select last row on page, instead first, for example). Better to do it way I describe in answer — break table in a few ones — start of table will guarantee first row (table must take at least 50% of page, so them will break correctly).

Answer (score 3):

Okey, direct answer — you can not do that as how you want.

**Edit:** oh, looks like I answer for a little more complicated question like "how to add table header on each printed page", but, anyway the way of solution is the same. Hope it's ok.

But there is several tricks to do what you want.

1) Break table in several parts, add thead part to each of them and remove margin, so it will looks like just one table. Add in css something like:

```
table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto;
}

table + table thead {
    display: none;
}
```

Also do not forget to set td width, cause tables without thead can have different width's.

After that add print styles:

```
@media print {
    table + table thead {
        display: table-column-group;
    }
}
```

Yep, there is a chance for duplicate headers on page, but it still better than nothing. And if you find good number of lines for your project it will looks as you need

2) Prepare dedicated downloaded printable version of page with [WKHTMLTOPDF](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf), for example. So you can catch page breaks well, and add what you need. This option give max flexibility of output, but will take some time for support.

3) Calculate everything with JS. Print your page and analyze it — add some constants to js (height per page), and, when someone try to print — calculate page breaks, find closest element and add what you need.

Hope you got answer.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to apply styles to only the first and last rows of a table over a page break, but maybe for a different use case.

I needed to give my whole table a border, but not on the table rows, just the outside. The easy way is to add a border to the table, but when a page break occurs, the borders aren't redrawn at the break.

My solution was to use a `thead` and `tfoot`, as these elements are repeated at every break. This gave me a full border around the table that obeyed page breaks.

You can modify this technique for your circumstances. Say if you wanted to change the styles of just the first row (and have it be consistent across page breaks), you just put that row in the `thead` or the `tfoot` depending on if you want the first or last row. You can even do this with an existing `thead`. Just give each `thead tr` a `class` so you know which is the main header, and which is a styled row.

There were a few caveats. The table footer had to have something within its `td`s otherwise it won't render. I added a `&nbsp;` (which means "no breaking space") to the first `td` and then set the `font-size` on the `td` to `1px` (Otherwise there will be a noticeable gap at the bottom of your table). The font size has to be applied directly to the `td`. A font size of `0` will not work either. It has to be non-zero.

### Example

This example is for my use case, but you can modify it. You can also use as many columns as you want. I used one for simplicity. The thead and tfoot must have the same number of columns though.

```
.my-table tr {border-left: 1px; border-right: 1px;}
.my-table thead {border-top: 1px;}
.my-table tfoot {border-bottom: 1px;}

// must be applied to the td!!!
.my-table tfoot td {font-size: 1px;}

<table class="my-table">
  <thead><td></td></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot><td>&nbsp;</td></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks so much for the hint that thead and tfoots get repeated at each page, back to layouting with tables but who cares 